# Running docker container inside Jenkins piepline

Tags: docker, jenkins

Once i try to run docker container inside jenkins pipeline it fails - [log](https://pastebin.com/BHhKFVDf). Jenkins is local. Since there's

> Jenkins does not seem to be running inside a container

line in console output i assume that in might be necessary to run containerized Jenkins?

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu

ENV customnEnvVar="test."
```

**Jenkinsfile**

```
#!groovy
pipeline {
    agent { dockerfile true }
    stages {
        steps {
            sh 'echo customEnvVar = $customEnvVar'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That code looks like it should be fine. I do notice the log is inconsistent with the code provided in the question.

Comment: it's my bad, i've cleaned code in question from unnecessary commands. Is it ok to run containers from local Jenkins or Jenkins should be conteinerized aswell?